# WebStorm Karma test runner EXTREMELY slow

Tags: karma-jasmine, webstorm, ng

Over 3500 tests for my entire app.

I'm trying to run tests for a specific file, which has 12 tests.

When I run this from the command line using `ng test`, it takes 10 seconds.

When I run this in WebStorm by clicking on the file and letting it figure out the default settings, it takes 3 minutes.

After the first 3 minute run, and it gets the Karma server up and running, it's plenty fast for a while... until the Karma server randomly crashes. But running from the command line is perfectly able to just launch a server, run the tests, then shut down the server in 10 seconds.

Any ideas on what I can do about this?